# 21.10 Removed Repositories?

Tags: 21.10

Need help with these errors, I'm running the Ubuntu version (21.10) from the Raspberry Pi Imager.

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports impish Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports impish-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports impish-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports impish-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.
~Blood

Comment: Support for Ubuntu 21.10 ended the 14th of July so yes there are no repositories and there are also NO update anymore. Please upgrade to 22.04 (that is an LTS). By the way that also means we do not support it anymore but a tip: change the url to the archive version if you need to install software (but it wont be newer versions)

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: **After** a release goes EOL its repositories are moved.  There is no set time for how long after, except the keyword used is **after**, which can mean the next day, weeks, even for some releases (eg. *hirsute*) it occurs months later.  Warnings of the EOL went out six weeks prior to EOL so you had warning (eg. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/06/01/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-14-2022/ for one), you also received messages on your box (*those could be dismissed including not show them again - if you opt to not show you again you're not re-warned*) so you were told.

Comment: Even if you missed the notices; 21.10 tells you it was the 2021-October release with 9 months of supported life; adding 9 to October tells you the month it'll EOL even without knowing the actual date (*notices tell you that, including the release notices*).  A quick count have reminded you.

Comment: Would this then be easier for me to just wipe the Raspberry Pi and use the imager to install this instead, rather than trying to update it from the Pi itself?

Comment: How is this off-topic?  It's not even possible to `dist-upgrade` because there is no way to install the impish `dist-upgrade` tool because the impish release file is missing...

Comment: Didn't know where else to put this, learning is learning. Didn't know this before hand.

Comment: `do-release-upgrade` worked for me for upgrading to 22.04.

Comment: @kyklops not for me, it tells me `Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.` which isn't possible given its current state.

Comment: This should not have been closed.  There must be a way to recover from this without reformatting the SD card and installing another OS.

Comment: For upgrading for versions which have reach end of life, Ubuntu provides this guide for updating to a newer version: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: that would have been a good answer instead of having the ticket closed.