# Upgrade to 22.04 (impish Release no longer has a Release file)

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, 22.04, repository

I am trying to `$ sudo apt update` but I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                        
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I haven't touched the `Software & updates - other software` OR the `sources.list` just in case someone asks.

Exact Ubuntu version.

`$ lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:    21.10
Codename:   impish
```

Edited: this question is about 22.04, not about 21.10, thanks for not closing it.

Comment: Same question [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1420077/590937)

Comment: Seems the same question was asked earlier than me.Thanks for the redirection.

Comment: I cannot post the answer since someone closed this as offtopic (sorry but this question is very much needed)

Here is what you need to do:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: I know it's not the place to complain, but where else can I.. They should have displayed a meaningfull human parseable message, like "cannot do `apt update`, your Ubuntu is not supported anymore, good bye"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are no more Canonical updates for Ubuntu 21.10 "Impish Indri" as of 14th July, that's why you can't update.

You can continue using 21.10 at the risk of e.g. security vulnerabilities that will no longer get patched but I would recommend upgrading to latest 22.04 "Jammy Jellyfish" LTE

Here is how to upgrade after EOL:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: It wasn't June, but July.   Refer https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/ with the warning notices going out six weeks before hand; you'll note they include *official* upgrade instructions which were QA tested too.

Comment: The question is, how to fix, remove, or improve that, since we did not do anything. I am using 22.04 but I am also receiving these messages.

Comment: Fact is that I really DO NOT LIKE the new Jammy Jellyfish **UI defacements**. I hate the square icons, the transparent menus, and... well I had a longer list when I tried it on a "battle" machine. I simply forgot it, since I wasn't interested in such an "upgrade" (I'd rather call it a `downgrade`).

Comment: It's not possible to upgrade to 22.04 *because* the 21.10 release file is missing...

Comment: `do-release-upgrade` worked for me for upgrading to 22.04.

Comment: I have absolutely nothing concrete to say other than fact that this Linux distro have become piece of s***. Nonsense. Garbage. Pathetic. etc. etc.

Comment: That canonical leaves people hanging like this is one of my most unfavorite things about ubuntu.

Comment: Following EOL guide above works, the key is editing the `/etc/apt/sources.list` so `archive.ubuntu.com` and `security.ubuntu.com` are changed to `old-releases.ubuntu.com`. This allows you to update/upgrade from an EOL version (e.g. Impish). Better instructions can be found here: https://askubuntu.com/a/91821/571221

Comment: do-release-upgrade stopped and prevented me from upgrading because i needed to update my existing system which of course i can't do.

Comment: It would have been good to get this as an error message instead of finding it hidden in the comments of an answer on Stack Overflow. Thank you for your help.

Comment: For me only this solution worked: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1385440/ubuntu-sudo-apt-get-update-404-not-found-problem